# send ID with href to php page with jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, href

So, I have a CRUD and one button to modify that should redirect to another page with the id of the person, I tried to do it with jquery this way

```
    fetchList()
function fetchList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'lista.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
            let task = JSON.parse(response);
            let template = '';
            task.forEach(task => {
                template +=
                    `<tr pacienteId="${task.id_pac}">
                    <td>${task.apellido}  </td>
                    <td>${task.nombre}</td>
                    <td>${task.dni}</td>
                    <td>${task.fecha_nacimiento}</td>
                    <td>${task.fecha_ingreso}</td>
                    <td>${task.obra_social}</td
                    // <td <span class="badge pacActivo">Activo</span> </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <a href="modificar.php" id="modificar" class="btn btn-sm butMod"></a>
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm butDel darBaja">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>`
            });
            $("#listadoPacientes").html(template);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the modify

```
    $(document).on('click', '#modificar', function (e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    let element = $(this)[0].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
    let id = $(element).attr('pacienteId')
    // Save information

    // Check if any ID is aviable 
    if (id) {
        // Save the url and perform a page load
         var direccion = href + '&id=' + id;
        window.open(direccion);
        console.log(id)

    } else {
        // Error handling
        alert('algo salio mal')
    }

})
```

but the problem it that I get this error:

> Undefined index: id in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\modulos\Pacientes\modificar.php

where i have the ID from jquery inside a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Solution:
   You append your `href` attribute in jQuery with only an "&". You need an "?" instead of an "&".
2. Solution: You put an GET parameter behinde your jQuery HTML build process `href`-tag.

Short you are generating an URL like:
`modificar.php&id=0`
correct is
`modificar.php**?**id=0`

Example:

```
if (id) {
        // Save the url and perform a page load
         var direccion = href + '?id=' + id; // changed the & to an ?
        window.open(direccion);
        console.log(id)

    } else {
        // Error handling
        alert('algo salio mal')
    }
```

Comment: Should also note ID's can't be repeated in page. Event listener will only work on first one